# Restrictions for xsd:decimal in WSDL

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap, wsdl

We are creating a SOAP Web Service using WCF, to be consumed by SAP.
From the SAP side they are asking that we specify restrictions for the decimal values in the XSD types declaration inside the WSDL. The problem is that WCF generates the Web Service without restrictions, and I don't know how to tell WCF to generate these restrictions (with attributes or something similar).
We want the xsd types to look like this:

```
    <xsd:simpleType name="LpgPorcType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
                  <xsd:totalDigits value="5" />
                  <xsd:fractionDigits value="2" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
```

Instead of this, the values in the WSDL are mapped directly to xsd:decimal
Is there any way to indicate to WCF that I need these restrictions (without manually editting the WSDL file)?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure you can make it generate the WSDL with what you want, but you could just validate it in code before/after you have it de/serialized.

Comment: Haven't tested it, but wouldn't the attributes from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations generate the WSDL you're looking for?

Comment: @Didaxis No, I thought that too but those attributes do not affect the generated WSDL, at least for decimals.

Comment: @TimS. I can validate the values, no problem there. The problem is that SAP is not being able to create the web service client without the restrictions explicitly set in the WSDL

Comment: Maybe you should use WSDL-first development, e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/24/wsdl-first-development-with-wcf.aspx

Comment: @TimS. That is possible, but I want to avoid that because we will have many web services, so that will force us to manually create or edit many WSDL files.

Comment: It's very unusual for a consumer of a service to specify the minutiae of the wsdl - as the service provider you should be specifying the wsdl definition. It's up to your consumers to deal with whatever is in it.

Comment: @GuillermoVasconcelos 7 Years later i ran into the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF does not support emitting this kind of restriction. You could put it yourself into the WSDL using [IWSDLExportExtension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/10/06/wcf-extensibility-wsdl-export-extension.aspx).